# Buffering stream of strings from socket

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, asynchronous, stream

I am working on a C# app that passes around strings between networked instances.

The code is currently using async sockets, and everything works great so far (localhost).

However, I am expecting buffering problems when the packets will be split and merged when I'll be going through real interfaces.

Client:

```
Socket sock;
// Snip init and connect

string msg1 = "Hello\nWorld";
byte[] data1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg1);
sock.Send(data1);

string msg2 = "Foo\nBar\nBaz";
byte[] data2 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg2);
sock.Send(data2);
```

I'd go with something like this, but I can't figure out an elegant solution to the missing bit:

Server:

```
Socket sock;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
Queue<string> strings = new Queue<string>();
// Snip init and receive connection
sock.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, MaxSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceived), null);

void OnReceived(IAsyncResult result) {
  // Snip sanity stuff
  int bytesReceived = sock.EndReceive(result);

  // Here is where I'd need some help...
  ms.Write(buffer, 0, bytesReceived);
  ms.Flush();
  for (;;) {
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
    if (sr.HasAStringTerminationCharacter) { // <-- How?
      string currentString = sr.ReadUntilTermination(); // <-- How?
      strings.Enqueue(currentString);
    }
    else
      break;
  }
  sock.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, MaxSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceived), null);
}
```

Comment: the msdn example located here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) looks as if it may help - check the ReadCallbackMethod

Comment: @Johnv2020 This made me realize that Encoding.GetBytes does not append or prepend string termination data, so there's no way to do that with that protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Encoding.GetBytes() does not prepend or append string termination data, I used BinaryReader/BinaryWriter instead, which encodes the string length before its content.

Here's the modified client:

```
Socket sock;
// Snip init and connect
sock.Send(ToBinary("Hello\nWorld"));
sock.Send(ToBinary("Foo\nBar\nBaz"));

byte[] ToBinary(string s) {
  var ms = new MemoryStream();
  var bw = new BinaryWriter(ms);
  bw.Write(s);
  bw.Flush();
  ms.Flush();
  return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Server:

```
Socket sock;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
Queue<string> strings = new Queue<string>();
// Snip init and receive connection
sock.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, MaxSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceived), null);

void OnReceived(IAsyncResult result) {
  // Snip sanity stuff
  int bytesReceived = sock.EndReceive(result);

  ms.Write(buffer, 0, bytesReceived);
  ms.Flush();
  long endPos = ms.Position;

  ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
  long readPos = ms.Position;
  var bw = new BinaryReader(ms);

  for (;;) {
    try {
      string currentString = bw.ReadString();
      strings.Enqueue(currentString);
      readPos = stream.Position;
    }
    catch (EndOfStreamException) {
      long unusedBytes = endPos - readPos;
      var remaining = new MemoryStream();
      remaining.Write(stream.GetBuffer(), (int) readPos, (int) unusedBytes);
      ms = remaining;
      break;
    }
  }
  sock.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, MaxSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceived), null);
}
```

I believe it will correctly handle split and merged data.